# remote connection using rdp protocol failure connecting to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, compiz, rdp

new install of 12.04 64 bit
installed vnc4server and xrdp
trying to connect remotely to it using rdp protocol
just getting blank screen with my desktop background
then dialog box saying /usr/bin/compiz "the application has closed unexpectently"
what can i try to allow me to access my desktop?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue just now. I think the problem is that compiz doesn't work correctly across the RDP connection on account of it needing a 3D card.
There are some solutions out there that tell you to change the gnome-session information. Doing this will leave you with an account that, when you log in on the local computer, will have none of the nice effects from your 3D card.

What I did to alleviate the problem was. On the Local Ubuntu computer:

1. Create a new user from > System Settings > User Accounts 
   (with same permissions as your normal account. I just used "username-rdp" where "username" is your current username)
2. Make sure the user is activated by giving it a password in the User Accounts window.
3. log in with that new user account
4. go to the terminal and run:

   ```
   echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > ~/.xsession
   ```
5. Restart the computer.

This should leave your computer in a state where your normal user is untouched and can still do 3D and Compiz. Your new user will work through the RDP connection and will be limited to the 2D Ubuntu session without harming your normal user.

If you don't care about 3D then just follow steps 4. and 5. and then use your normal user account over RDP.

Answer (score 1):

I always create a new user for remote desktop connectivity. This way your normal account settings will not be affected by changes in the .xsession settings.

In 12.04 for Gnome-Classic with no effects use:

```
echo "gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback" > ~/.xsession
```